# List value not populating in table in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC. I have created a .NET fiddle example. This is the URL:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/R9eldA

I can not see `ID` and `Name` value in the table.

Comment: Change to  `<td>@report.Id</td><td><a href="#">@report.Name</a></td>`. Your iteration variable is called `report`, not `r`.

Comment: Thank you Victor. It worked. Why did we use @?

Comment: @also can you plz post it as an Answer. I marked it resolved.

Comment: @ tells the aspnet rendering engine to use the variable/property `report.id`, rather than just printing `report.id` literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like typo error. Just change to:

```
@foreach (var report in Model.Reports)
{                           
    <tr>        
        <td>@report.Id</td>                                
        <td><a href="#">@report.Name</a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

About the `@` symbol see the following description from the Microsoft [documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#razor-syntax)

> Razor supports C# and uses the **`@`** symbol to transition from HTML to C#.
> Razor evaluates C# expressions and renders them in the HTML output.